# micronaut not allowing two controllers derived from same base class (that implements an interface) to be registered with router

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

Seems like Micronaut is not allowing two controllers inherited from the same base class (that implements an interface) to be registered with the router.

Here is my simplified code that throws the same exception:
Then I get this exception:

```
package hello.world
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get

interface RestOperations {
    @Get("/{id}")
    fun read(id: Long): Map<String, Any?>
}

open class RestController : RestOperations {
    @Get("/{id}")
    override fun read(id: Long): Map<String, Any?> {
        return mapOf("number" to id)
    }
}

@Controller("/foo")
class FooController : RestController() {}

@Controller("/bar")
class BarController : RestController() {}
```

This will work for only one controller.  It will also work if you remove the interface RestOperations from RestController.

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed 
to inject value for parameter [router] of class: 
io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultRouter
```

Long stack trace originating with Netty... ending in:

```
Caused by: 
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: 
Error instantiating bean of 
type[io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultRouter]
```

Let me know if you have any ideas.  Thank you.

Comment: With this level of details is hard to tell. If you believe it's an issue, please report it here: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues

Comment: Thanks.  I did and Graeme has labeled it a bug.

Comment: For future reference to potential users, it'd be great if you can share here the link to the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/936

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed a bug and fixed for 1.0.2